# How to reload or refresh Windows Form into original state?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to reload or refresh the Windows Form into original state? i have used this.Refresh();,this.Invalidate();,form.Refresh(),form.Invalidate()

```
private void AdduserBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserManagement obj = new UserManagement ();
    obj.CourseCategoryId = (int) CourseRegCbox.SelectedValue;
    obj.IDNumber = IDNumberTbox.Text;
    obj.Password = PasswordRegTbox.Text;
    obj.FName = FnameRegTbox.Text;
    obj.LName = LnameRegTbox.Text;
    obj.Gender = GenderTbox.Text;
    obj.Email = EmailRegTbox.Text;
    obj.PhoneNumber = PhonenumberRegTbox.Text;
    obj.Address = AddressRegTbox.Text;

    if ( UserManagement != null && UserManagement.Id > 0 )
    {
        obj.Id = UserManagement.Id;
        if ( UserManagement.UserInfo_Update (obj) > 0 )
        {
            MessageBox.Show ("Record Succesfully Updated!");
            UserInfoForm form = new UserInfoForm ();
            form.Refresh ();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show ("An error occured!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ( UserManagement.UserInfo_Insert (obj) > 0 )
        {
            MessageBox.Show ("Record Succesfully Added!");
            UserInfoForm form = new UserInfoForm ();
            form.Refresh ();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show ("An error occured!");
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to reload the form into original state once the data properly save or updated.

Comment: What form is your above code in? is it a UserInfoForm ? Because if it is you are keeping the main form visible, creating a new UserInfoForm not showing it and trying to refresh it.

Comment: Yeah, im keeping the main form visible, when i add the data and when it is successfully saved, the main form will be reloaded or it will be refresh to its original state..it is like the form is freshly loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "this.Refresh();,this.Invalidate();,form.Refresh(),form.Invalidate()"

These functions just tell the window manager to redraw the form graphic; they have nothing to do with the state of the form's data.

Seems that all you need to do is set your control values back to their original values So, make a function on the form:

```
 private void ResetForm()
    {
       //write code here to setup your dropdowns, put empty strings into textboxes, etc.
       //pretty much the reverse of the process by which you copy the values into your user object.
    }
```

and then in the sucess part of the code call the function:

```
if ( UserManagement.UserInfo_Update (obj) > 0 )
            {
                MessageBox.Show ("Record Succesfully Updated!");
                //reset this form, no need to make another one...
                ResetForm();
            }
```

and you can also include a call to `ResetForm()` somewhere in your `Form_Load`, etc.

**However**

I'd recommend that once you are comfortable with doing this, you then **stop doing it** and use the [data-binding facility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that's built into Winforms; what it allows you to do is use the designer to bind user interface elements on the form (textboxes, etc) to various Class properties (e.g. `UserManagement` class).

This way you can simply "reset" your form by creating a new instance of `UserManagement` without having to deal with all the cruddy details of clearing out textboxes, etc. Otherwise you will find as your objects grow more complex, writing the code to manually reset form UI elments becomes more and more tedious and error-prone.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice answer as far as I am concerned. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. You must create a new form object and close current form.

```
 Form fr = new Form();
     fr.Show();
     this.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this by closing and opening the form. So replace the ***** with your form name

```
        ***your form name** ss = new **your form name***();
        ss.Show();
        this.Hide();
```

I would also recommend putting a form close to fully close the form:

```
 private void ***Your form name***Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
this.Controls.Clear();
this.InitializeComponent();
```

Comment: If possible then please explain how this code works by providing comments along with the code.